# How to remove time from a date filter

Tags: excel, vba, date, filter

How can I delete time from date?

I am trying to filter my sheet but I always have a time in the filter.

```vb
Sub filtr()    
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_owssvr").Range.AutoFilter Field:=12, _
      Criteria1:=">=" & (Now - 3), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & (Now)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *Date*:

```
Criteria1:=">=" & (Date - 3), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Date
```